# Raman Spectrum processing in Java

Tags: java

I have 2D array of type doubles as spectral data in text file. I have to find peaks in the spectrum. I am using Binary Search to find peaks in the array, but I am getting false peaks also. How can I filter the result I am getting. If anybody know about this please help me

Here is the code which I am using

```
static ArrayList < Double > nPeaks(double[] array, int range) {

  if (array == null) {
    System.out.println("Error");
  }

  double result = 0, l, r;
  double[] peaks = null;

  // Check main body
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    boolean isPeak = true;
    // Check from left to right
    l = Math.max(0, i - range);
    r = Math.min(array.length - 1, i + range);
    for (int j = (int) l; j <= r; j++) {
      // Skip if we are on current
      if (i == j) {
        continue;
      }
      if (array[i] < array[j]) {
        isPeak = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isPeak) {

      //System.out.println("Peak at " + i + " = " + array[i]);
      peaklist.add(array[i]);
      result++;
      i += range;
    }
  }

  return peaklist;
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing it yourself instead of using Arrays.binarySearch? In any case, binary searching requires sorted data, and 'finding peaks' is certainly not something which you tend to do on sorted data. You need to rethink entire aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me. I assume you are generating the max to min order of input array. If yes, you are trying to create a sorted array(descending order).

Simply sort the array in descending order. That will have result like

peak1, peak2, peak3...peakn

where,
peak1 - is max value

peakn - is min value

Comment: No I am not sorting it and I don't want max min values I want only the regions with more deviation.

Comment: can you share sample input and sample output.

Comment: Input array={1099.5054,1075.5621,1097.5502,1079.3259,1080.0361,1080.5549,1079.4446,1080.8217,1080.9097,1081.39,1081.0564,1079.259,1080.9725,1081.027,1080.5486,1081.2754,1079.1895,1079.5299,1079.1648,1078.1195,1077.5784,1075.3386,1075.3075,1074.4132,1075.8834}
 Output:                                                                                                                    
Peak at 0 = 1099.5054
Peak at 9 = 1081.39
Peak at 15 = 1081.2754
Peak at 24 = 1075.8834
Peak at 31 = 1078.5387

Comment: Add the sample range for this input. So that I can co-relate.

Comment: sample range is 2

Comment: sorry I could not understand the logic in this example. But I found the below link which may solve your problem

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=TarsosDSP-master/src/core/be/tarsos/dsp/beatroot/Peaks.java

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to find peaks in spectrum is calculating the disspersion of whole spectrum and then devile it by 3*sigma and take floor funstion. After it you shold "see" only peaks and each place higher than 1 shold be a peak